# Using expressjs, how can i return default img if no file is found in public folder?

Tags: node.js, url, express

I have a public folder with avatars ...

```
127.0.0.1/avatar/5928369292385
```

It's okay for existing files but when the file is missing:

```
Cannot GET /avatar/ef7649059214769a0fefew
```

How can i return a default image of my choosing when requests are made for non existing files?

Comment: Can you please post the code for your routed function?  ( app.get(..THIS..) ) ; or is it a static function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-arribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-valid

Comment: It is in the static/public folder.

Comment: Try with the answer to this other question [stackoverflow.com/questions/14124924/node-js-express-sending-static-files-if-they-exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124924/node-js-express-sending-static-files-if-they-exist)